# Individuals or persons?

Tags: expressions

In describing my company's services, which of the following phrases is more respectful: "these services are for individuals who can..." or, "these services are for persons who can..."?

Comment: It's entirely a matter of opinion which of your two suggestions would be considered more "respectful". But if you want to know which form is more ***common***, things are [for **people** who can (appreciate them, whatever)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+for+individuals+who+can%2Care+for+persons+who+can%2Care+for+people+who+can&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20for%20people%20who%20can%3B%2Cc0), by a huge margin (neither of your suggestions occur often enough to figure on that chart).

Comment: Persons is out, but individuals could work if we can hear what comes right before and right after your phrases.

Comment: I think "individuals" can be contrasted with companies or corporate bodies.   So if your service is for corporate clients then individuals might not be good. Rather than person or individual is there a word for your customer type  e.g. travellers, gardeners, dog--lovers, householders? If so you might consider that if you can do so  without  narrowing your market.  ,

Answer (score -2):

To answer your question, I agree with @I.M.H; they are both very similar.

But consider *party*

Although *party* usually refers to a group of people, it can also be used to refer to either, a group or a person, and I feel it is more highbrow than either of the above.

E.g. from renowned fiction writer Haruki Murakami's novel Wind/Pinball:

"I dialed information and gave the operator her name, but after searching for five minutes she came back on the line to announce that no party by that name was listed in the directory."

source: https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=WMDTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT48&lpg=PT48&dq=haruki+murakami+no+party+by+that+name&source=bl&ots=AsMOBzstVP&sig=biFBG8phOBHTVXhtPQxJp8hzpqA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG-bOD__vSAhUmLsAKHZvQAp4Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=haruki%20murakami%20no%20party%20by%20that%20name&f=false

So I would use something like, "These services are intended/provided for parties with advanced programming skills."